# Toast else com problemas

Tags: java, android

Meu *toast* está sendo mostrado mesmo quando meu *else* não é chamado; era pra ser mostrado apenas quando o usuário digitar senha ou e-mail errado, mas mesmo quando o `equals` funciona, o *toast* aparece:

```
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);


    try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

        System.out.println(json.getString("resource"));
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json.getString("resource"));
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("Email : " + jsonObj.getString("tx_email"));
            System.out.println("Password : " + jsonObj.getString("password"));
            String email = jsonObj.getString("tx_email");
            String password = jsonObj.getString("password");
            String nickteste = jsonObj.getString("tx_nickname");
            String cellteste = jsonObj.getString("nu_cellphone");
            String snome = jsonObj.getString("tx_name");


            if (mEmail.equals(email) && mPassword.equals(password)) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                //startActivity(intent);

                //Intent ii = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivityAttCad.class);
                intent.putExtra("mEmail", email);
                intent.putExtra("mPassword", password);
                intent.putExtra("mNick", nickteste);
                intent.putExtra("mCellphone", cellteste);
                intent.putExtra("mNome", snome);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            else {


                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ou senha inválido(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast.show();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toast.cancel();
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }





    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}}
```

Comment: Talvez seja falha minha mas a parte if (mEmail.equals(email) && mPassword.equals(password)) { ... não deveria estar fora do loop for ?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você está comparando vários dados lidos de um arquivo JSON com o email e a senha. Provavelmente apenas um desses dados corresponde à condição no `if`, assim, nos outros, ele cai no `else`

Comment: O codigo esta correto. Sugiro debugar para analisar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Você está testando o usuário/senha dentro de um loop que varre toda a lista de usuários retornados do servidor, então o if-else está rodando diversas vezes até o fim do loop. Em algum ponto do loop, o usuário/senha batem com o esperado (e não mostra o Toast) e nas outras iterações do loop (provavelmente todas as demais), o usuário/senha não batem e exibem o Toast.

Eu modificaria o loop dessa forma:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("Email : " + jsonObj.getString("tx_email"));
        System.out.println("Password : " + jsonObj.getString("password"));
        String email = jsonObj.getString("tx_email");
        String password = jsonObj.getString("password");
        String nickteste = jsonObj.getString("tx_nickname");
        String cellteste = jsonObj.getString("nu_cellphone");
        String snome = jsonObj.getString("tx_name");


        if (mEmail.equals(email)){
            if(mPassword.equals(password)) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                //startActivity(intent);

                //Intent ii = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivityAttCad.class);
                intent.putExtra("mEmail", email);
                intent.putExtra("mPassword", password);
                intent.putExtra("mNick", nickteste);
                intent.putExtra("mCellphone", cellteste);
                intent.putExtra("mNome", snome);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else {


                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ou senha inválido(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast.show();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toast.cancel();
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Está dando um erro nessa linha : if (mEmail.equals(email){
                        if(mPassword.equals(password)) {

Comment: Já fiz a correção,ótimo código ,obrigada

Comment: O código esta correto. Sugiro debugar para analisar melhor.